# Cambiar texto de botón

Tags: android

de nuevo molestando y agradeciéndoles su ayuda de antemano, le comento que tengo un problema nuevamente con Android,

Lo que  trato de hacer es que el botón muestre un variable o un texto diferente, este es el codigo que tengo:

ejecuto un método que obtiene los datos de MYSQL, este método lo llamo desde el bundle.

codigo completo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editarhijo_menu);


 //// LLAMMAOS EL REG ID PARA LA CONSULTA
    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID ES: " + regId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    //////MUESTRA LOS DAOTS PARA COMPROBAR QUE SI LOS TENEMOS //////
    //   mivariableexterna = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero);
   // nombre_padre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rpadre);
   // cel_padre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rcelpadre);
    //hijo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rhijo1);
    //hijo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rhijo2);
    //hijo3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rhijo3);
    //hijo4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rhijo4);//


    hijo1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.h1);
    hijo1.setOnClickListener(this);

    hijo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.h2);
    hijo2.setOnClickListener(this);
    // register listeners
    hijo3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.h3);
    hijo3.setOnClickListener(this);

    hijo4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.h4);
    hijo4.setOnClickListener(this);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(EditarHijo_Menu.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if GCM configuration is set ///// checa la configuracion en php
    if (SERVER_URL == null || SENDER_ID == null || SERVER_URL.length() == 0
            || SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {
        // GCM sernder id / server url is missing
        alert.showAlertDialog(EditarHijo_Menu.this, "Configuration Error!",
                "Please set your Server URL and GCM Sender ID", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    VerificarInternet tarea = new VerificarInternet(EditarHijo_Menu.this, new VerificarInternet.EntoncesHacer() {
        @Override
        public void cuandoHayInternet() {

            new CreateUser().execute(); ////LANZAMOS EL OBJETO QUE VA MOSTRAR LOS DATOS
        }
        public void cuandoNOHayInternet() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lo sentimos no hay internet",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    tarea.execute();
}


public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.h1:
            Intent w = new Intent(this, RegisterActivityAlterno.class);
            startActivity(w);

            break;
        case R.id.h2:
            Intent j = new Intent(this, RegisterActivityAlterno_nuevomovil.class);
            startActivity(j);

            break;

        case R.id.h3:
            Intent k = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity_papa2.class);
            startActivity(k);

            break;


        case R.id.h4:
            Intent g = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity_papa2.class);
            startActivity(g);

            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}


class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditarHijo_Menu.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Espere porfavor...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String regid = regId;

        try {


            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", regid));


            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);  



            primerhijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO1);
            segundohijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO2);
            tercerhijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO3);
            cuartohijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO4);




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
          //  Toast.makeText(EditarHijo_Menu.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            String hij1 = String.valueOf(primerhijo);
            hijo1.setText(hij1);

            String hij2 = String.valueOf(segundohijo);
            hijo2.setText(hij2);

            String hij3 = String.valueOf(tercerhijo);
            hijo3.setText(hij3);

            String hij4 = String.valueOf(cuartohijo);
            hijo4.setText(hij4);


            p2_button.setText("hij2");

           Button p3_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.h3);
           p3_button.setText("hij3");

           Button p4_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.h4);
           p4_button.setText("hij4");



        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Jesus, dataobtenido se obtiene en doInBackground() ? "en el bundle tengo los botones", es imposible tener en un bundle los botones, agrega tu código :P

Comment: en seguida XD, arriba actualizo información de la pregunta saludos

Comment: En tu  doInBackground() agrega un breakpoint y revisa si tienes datos en :   primerhijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO1);
            segundohijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO2);
            tercerhijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO3);
            cuartohijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO4); tal vez ese es el problema que no puede realizar:  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys  el problema estaba en el código PHP XD

Comment: En que parte?, ya viste mi respuesta?  no va a funcionar correctamente si no quitas ese if :P

Comment: Te recomendaria que uses Retrofit en vez de Asynctask. Te va a servir mas para usarlo con multiple conecciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que se obtienen datos del proceso en `doInBackground()` :

```
   JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);  

            primerhijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO1);
            segundohijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO2);
            tercerhijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO3);
            cuartohijo = json.getString(TAG_HIJO4);
```

Elimina el if:

```
if (file_url != null){
```

ya que se recibe un valor null en `file_url` dentro del método `onPostExecute()` :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        //if (file_url != null){ //* ELIMINA ESTA LINEA!
        ... 
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

En el código que adjuntas, el método `doInBackground` devuelve `null`, así que no se cumple la condición del `if` del método `onPostExecute`.
En cuanto arregles eso, debería de resolverse tu problema.

Un saludo